# How to set width of bokeh plot x-axis directly

Tags: python, bokeh

I would like to define the width of my bokeh plots *excluding* ylabels.

I am making a `gridplot()` and the subplots have different xranges, but it's important they are have the same scale.

I can define the width in proportion to their xrange, but that doesn't quite work, as the size of the y axis label, throws it off slightly.

I have a workaround, which is to estimate the size of the ylabel in pixels, then add that to the width, but it's far from an ideal solution.

[image]

As you can see the bottom panel is slightly stretched.

Comment: Even a way to calculate the width of the y-axis labels would be extremely useful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no direct way to do that. You have direct control over:

- The `plot_width` and `plot_height`. These are the (pixel) dimensions of the entire HTML canvas (which includes axes and titles, etc.)

and

- The `min_border` (and specific `min_border_left`, etc) properties. The let you provide a *mimimum* pixel size for the areas around the central plot area (i.e. where axes and titles live).

So if you want to exert finer control over the central plot region, you can control these two things to do it. E.g. if you make two plots with `plot_width` of 600 and give both `min_border_left` of 80, then as long as the axes and labels, etc. of both plots fit inside the 80 pixels the cental plot areas will have the same width of 520px.

Comment: I’m struggling with this at the moment. Because it’s hard to reason about the size of the central plot region, Bokeh figures are not very compositional. As per the comment above, a stepwise improvement would be the ability to calculate the width of (axes + labels), or set it to some fixed size (with content clipped).

Comment: The width of the axis and labels is not computed by any Python code, it is only computed in the browser, in JavaScript code. So the first option is not possible in principle, except in the Bokeh server case (and even then, only retro-actively after the fact). A fixed size with clipping could be possible, but no one has ever asked for that as a feature, so it's never been considered. Please feel free to open a [github issue](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues) to propose it.